# Server Tomcat version 7.0 not working in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse-indigo

I am getting the things displayed in console as below

I am new to eclipse so i don't know how to solve this please help me

```
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Testmail' did not find a matching property.
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Talentakeaways' did not find a matching property.
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 15 2016 16:27:45 UTC
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.70.0
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.6.0_18-b07
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Sun Microsystems Inc.
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Bharat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Bharat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: Files
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: (x86)\Apache
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: Software
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: Foundation\Tomcat
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: 7.0
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Bharat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: Files
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: (x86)\Apache
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: Software
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: Foundation\Tomcat
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: 7.0\endorsed
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin;;D:\Meena Android\Android\eclipse;
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8082"]
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 572 ms
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.1) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Testmail]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Testmail]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> Emailer in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3385)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:887)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5503)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Bharat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Talentakeaways\WEB-INF\lib\javaee.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\Bharat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Talentakeaways\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 11 more
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8082"]
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8082"]
8 Aug, 2016 2:51:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I have tried all possible things explained in google

1. Removing and re-adding server
2. Deleting snap file in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
3. Restarting system after removing tomcat and again adding 
   nothing helped me

Please help in alternate solutions

Thanks in advance